# Magento 2 How to change position for buttons on product add/edit form?

Tags: magento2, product

How can I change the position of **Save**, **Save & Close** buttons on the product add/edit?

I need to place the "Save & close" button first instead of "Save" button on the product add/edit form.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save">
        <plugin name="SR_MagentoCommunity::change_product_button_position"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/Save.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Control\Container;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable as ConfigurableType;

class Save
{
    /**
     * Url Builder
     *
     * @var Context
     */
    protected $context;

    /**
     * Registry
     *
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * Generic constructor
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Generate url by route and parameters
     *
     * @param string $route
     * @param array $params
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->context->getUrl($route, $params);
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return ProductInterface
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }


    public function aroundGetButtonData(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        //return $proceed();
        if ($this->getProduct()->isReadonly()) {
            return [];
        }

        return [
            'id_hard' => 'save_and_close',
            'label' => __('Save & Close'),
            'class' => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => $this->getSaveTarget(),
                                'actionName' => $this->getSaveAction(),
                                'params' => [
                                    true
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'class_name' => Container::SPLIT_BUTTON,
            'options' => $this->getOptions(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        $options[] = [
            'id_hard' => 'save-button',
            'label' => __('Save'),
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => $this->getSaveTarget(),
                                'actionName' => $this->getSaveAction(),
                                'params' => [
                                    false
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ];

        $options[] = [
            'id_hard' => 'save_and_new',
            'label' => __('Save & New'),
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => $this->getSaveTarget(),
                                'actionName' => $this->getSaveAction(),
                                'params' => [
                                    true,
                                    [
                                        'back' => 'new'
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ];

        if (!$this->context->getRequestParam('popup') && $this->getProduct()->isDuplicable()) {
            $options[] = [
                'label' => __('Save & Duplicate'),
                'id_hard' => 'save_and_duplicate',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => [
                        'buttonAdapter' => [
                            'actions' => [
                                [
                                    'targetName' => $this->getSaveTarget(),
                                    'actionName' => $this->getSaveAction(),
                                    'params' => [
                                        true,
                                        [
                                            'back' => 'duplicate'
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
            ];
        }

        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve target for button.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getSaveTarget()
    {
        $target = 'product_form.product_form';
        if ($this->isConfigurableProduct()) {
            $target = 'product_form.product_form.configurableVariations';
        }
        return $target;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve action for button.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getSaveAction()
    {
        $action = 'save';
        if ($this->isConfigurableProduct()) {
            $action = 'saveFormHandler';
        }
        return $action;
    }

    /**
     * Is configurable product.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function isConfigurableProduct()
    {
        return !$this->getProduct()->isComposite() || $this->getProduct()->getTypeId() === ConfigurableType::TYPE_CODE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this code work with configurable product or all type of products?

Comment: For all product types

Comment: One quick question I have what is the use of "getUrl()" function here? is it necessary?

Comment: Thanks for your support. it is working for all products. :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify them with CSS. Make their container `display:flex` add a `flex-direction` and then on the save & close button put `order:1` and `order:2` on the save button. Here is a link for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Comment: Thanks for your help but it will only show the dropdown options as buttons. but I need to change the position of buttons and show "save & close" as first instead of "Save" button.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you're looking at so I can better understand?